# Deletion of data from replica db mysql

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I was thinking of deleting millions of rows in a production database, but due to fear of downtime, I wanted to know how much time this bulk delete operation gonna take. That's why I thought why not give a try in replica DB. What we have in production DB is mirrored into replica DB, so if I delete anything from replica DB, are those deleted data again gonna come back from production DB?

I have prepared the script for deleting bulk data from the database. But I'm not sure about the consequence, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: This is a great argument for a soft delete design.  With a "deleted" flag, you would have many more options.  With that said, batch the deletes into small groups of 100-1000 rows.  You provided no information about how you need to identify the universe of rows to be deleted, but it's important that your delete query be efficient and use an index.  With that said, just look at the math on the deletions.  You could for example, run a 1000 row delete batch via a cron job or scheduled job in mysql, once every 10 seconds, and a 1m row deletion job will be accomplished in a little over 2 hours.

Comment: Deleting 1000 rows is still a substantial amount of overhead, so you will probably have a smoother experience with smaller batches.  100-200 rows every 5-10 seconds, and you still get your database to the place you want it to be within a day.  You also didn't say whether or not you are using innodb.  Innodb provides row locking and transactions whereas myisam doesn't.  Even with innodb, if you are doing this to clear space, unless you are using per table tablespace, you won't recover disk space, although the empty space will be reallocated over time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. they will come back.
The best way to delete data is using a primary key from the prod db and use batch size.
The <> will be a batch size of say 1000 or 5000 or so.
`where pk in (<<list of keys>>)`
In our prod env, we use batch size that varies from 20 to 1000 depending on the database as it may potentially lead to table locking and causes significant latency.